# Python Pandas Error while Tokenizing Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe

I'm trying to use Pandas to use a csv file, and I keep seeing this:

```
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 12
```

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ZCS006A_16_23AUG_ALL_20220804020843.csv', delimiter = ',')
df.head(10)
```

Should I modify my code or modify the csv file?

This is part of the .cvs file:

AIRLINE_CODE,FLIGHT_NO,AIRCRAFT_TYPE_CODE,DEP_PORT_CODE,ARR_PORT_CODE,DEP_DATE,ARR_DATE,STD,STA,BLOCK_TIME,LEG,PART_NO,PART_NAME,PART_DESC,PART_SECTOR_USAGE_CODE,PART_SECTOR_USAGE_NAME,PART_CATEGORY_CODE,PAX_CLASS,EXCHANGE_TYPE_CODE,PART_QTY,PART_WEIGHT,IS_DEADHEAD LA,0800,789,AKL,SCL,16-AUG-22,16-AUG-22,1840,1340,660,2,10002993,MANTEQUILLA YC,10002993: MANTEQUILLA YC,D,Disposable,,Y,CY,143,35.75,0 LA,0800,789,AKL,SCL,16-AUG-22,16-AUG-22,1840,1340,660,2,10003049,BEBIDA BLANCA 1500CC YC,10003049: BEBIDA BLANCA 1500CC YC,D,Disposable,,Y,BX,4,6.5332,0 LA,0800,789,AKL,SCL,16-AUG-22,16-AUG-22,1840,1340,660,2,10003049,BEBIDA BLANCA 1500CC YC,10003049: BEBIDA BLANCA 1500CC YC,D,Disposable,,Y,EX,6,9.7998,0 LA,0800,789,AKL,SCL,16-AUG-22,16-AUG-22,1840,1340,660,2,10003153,COCA COLA 1500CC YC,10003153: COCA COLA 1500CC YC,D,Disposable,,Y,BX,4,6.4,0 LA,0800,789,AKL,SCL,16-AUG-22,16-AUG-22,1840,1340,660,2,10003153,COCA COLA 1500CC YC,10003153: COCA COLA 1500CC YC,D,Disposable,,Y,EX,8,12.8,0

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and copy-paste part of the CSV file? (The first 10 lines would do)

Comment: It has been edited.

Comment: The snippet you've included runs fine on my side. But it looks like the CSV is malformed somehow as it contains 24 fields and not 2 like the error is saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `pandas` documentation, `pd.read_csv` says:

> error_bad_lines bool, optional, default None
>
> Lines with too many fields (e.g. a csv line with too many commas) will
> by default cause an exception to be raised, and no DataFrame will be
> returned. If False, then these “bad lines” will be dropped from the
> DataFrame that is returned.

So, you may pass parameter `error_bad_lines=False` to `pd.read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ZCS006A_16_23AUG_ALL_20220804020843.csv', delimiter = ',', error_bad_lines=False)
```